# Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} [(\ln n)^n-n^{\ln n}]$

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate$$\lim_{n\to \infty} [(\ln n)^n-n^{\ln n}].$$

I tried to write in the form $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{\ln n}[\frac{(\ln n)^n}{n^{\ln n}}-1].$$
I tried to write but I have difficulty as to calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(\ln n)^n}{n^{\ln n}}.$$

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$(\ln n)^n-n^{\ln n}=e^{n\ln\ln n}-e^{(\ln n)^2}$$
and as $n\to \infty$
$$n\ln\ln n>(\ln n)^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Letting $n = e^x$, $(\ln{n})^n - n^{\ln{n}} = x^{e^x} - e^{x^2}$. The first term is a granddaddy of the 2nd term so the limit is infinity.